# need rollover effect for row of 9 perfume bottles

Tags: jquery, effect, performance, rollover

For a perfumer's website I'm displaying a row of nine bottles on a shelf. It appears as one continuous photograph. I've cut it into nine seamless slices, each in its own table cell with its own id.

I'm thinking to use jQuery as I want the following on rollover:

- Bottle blitzes instantaneously bright also triggers short sound file.
- After a millisecond or two, returns to normal state.
- Action repeats only if blurred and re-moused over.
- Effect the same for each of the 9 bottles.

Mousedown (click) probably doesn't need an effect, just targets that particular bottle's page into the front page's iframe.
I've made 9 alt. slices that are white-outs, but don't know how to write script with timed effect.

Flash? Please, don't even go there; it makes me plain nuts. OTOH, I find jQuery to be elegant.

Maybe momentarily putting a white sprite over the image at the beginning of rollover is easier? How would I go about doing that?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh please don't add sound on hover. It get's old fast. I know this as I was once tasked to add a site owner's voice to the primary navigation on a page.

Comment: Sweet jesus....that must have been terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the script to implement the rollover images to start with? If so, then all you need to add is a call to jQuery's `.delay()` with the functionality of disabling the rollover image. More info on the `.delay()` function is available [from the jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

If you need help getting the rollover up and going, you might find what you're looking for in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887432/javascript-image-rollover).

Comment: I guess the answerer means (below), but divs are in 2 classes already.. This is over my head.. can someone simplify it for me?:
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function(){
    $('.images img').hover(
        function(){
                $(this).parents('.images').find('img').not(this).animate({"opacity": "0.3"}, 200);
                $(this).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 200);
        }, 
        function(){
                $(this).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 200);
        }
    );
$('.images').bind('mouseleave',function(){$(this).find('img').animate({"opacity": "1"}, 200);});
});

Comment: I'm not adept enough to use the script above. I haven't the faintest idea how to adapt it to my table divisions which are already in two classes. Can I add yet more classes to these divisions?

Comment: Your original post made it sound like you had the initial rollover up and going. Was that incorrect? I'm completely tied up with stuff tonight, but I will put some code together for you once I'm free if no one else has done so.

Comment: Thank you so much !!!! I'd appreciate that. No I don't have anything yet. Just the divisions made with the slices in them.

Comment: Could someone else please just spell out a script for me? Unfortunately, I don't know how to use the given information. I'm not adept enough... now just even more frustrated.. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this with no jQuery at all: just straight-up Javascript. In your Javascript code, you'll need two functions for handling the images:

```
function imgOn(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).src = 'img_on.jpg';
    setTimeout("imgOff('"+id+"')",1000);
}

function imgOff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).src = 'img_off.jpg';
}
```

The key parts here are that you set the image files correctly and set the timeout you desire. Replace `img_on.jpg` with the filename for the white bottle, and replace `img_off.jpg` with the filename for the normal bottle. Also, it is set to revert back after 1 second. To adjust this time, change the `1000` to a different value.

Then when you actually show the image(s), use the following HTML:

```
<span onMouseOver="imgOn('img1');" onMouseOut="imgOff('img1');">
  <img id="img1" src="img_off.jpg">
</span>
```

Make sure that each image has a unique value for id, and that the value you use for id is also used in the onMouseOver and onMouseOut calls. If these images are functioning as links, you can use the following instead:

```
<a href='page.html' onMouseOver="imgOn('img1');" onMouseOut="imgOff('img1');">
  <img id="img1" src="img_off.jpg">
</a>
```